# How to catch Stripe Invalidrequest exception error in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin, stripe-payments

I am following this [link](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse) to implement stripe in Android. When I enter test card number from diners or discover, I am getting the below error.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
> Process: com.xxxxx.app, PID: 11990
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Request-id: req_edpbJzvr4Zkk9V
> com.stripe.android.exception.InvalidRequestException: Your card is not supported.
> at android.os.Parcel.writeException(Parcel.java:1590)
> at com.stripe.android.PaymentController$Result.writeToParcel(PaymentController.kt)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeParcelable(Parcel.java:1505)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1411)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:733)
> at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1408)
> at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1133)
> at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:773)
> at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:9247)
> at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3511)
> at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1526)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4399)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:676)
> at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4358)
> at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:663)
> at com.stripe.android.view.AuthActivityStarter$Host.startActivityForResult$stripe_release(AuthActivityStarter.kt:33)
> at com.stripe.android.PaymentRelayStarter$Companion$create$1.start(PaymentRelayStarter.kt:28)
> at com.stripe.android.PaymentRelayStarter$Companion$create$1.start(PaymentRelayStarter.kt:21)
> at com.stripe.android.StripePaymentController$Companion.handleError(StripePaymentController.kt:899)
> at com.stripe.android.StripePaymentController$Companion.access$handleError(StripePaymentController.kt:838)
> at com.stripe.android.StripePaymentController$ConfirmStripeIntentCallback.onError(StripePaymentController.kt:542)
> at com.stripe.android.ApiOperation.dispatchResult(ApiOperation.kt:40)
> at com.stripe.android.ApiOperation.access$dispatchResult(ApiOperation.kt:13)
> at com.stripe.android.ApiOperation$execute$1$1.invokeSuspend(ApiOperation.kt:32)
> at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
> at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
> at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
> at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
> at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
> Caused by: Request-id: req_edpbJzvr4Zkk9V
> com.stripe.android.exception.InvalidRequestException: Your card is not supported.
> at com.stripe.android.StripeApiRepository.handleApiError(StripeApiRepository.kt:875)
> at com.stripe.android.StripeApiRepository.makeApiRequest$stripe_release(StripeApiRepository.kt:919)
> at com.stripe.android.StripeApiRepository.fetchStripeModel(StripeApiRepository.kt:903)
> at com.stripe.android.StripeApiRepository.confirmSetupIntent(StripeApiRepository.kt:212)
> at com.stripe.android.StripePaymentController$ConfirmStripeIntentTask.getResult$stripe_release(StripePaymentController.kt:524)
> at com.stripe.android.ApiOperation$execute$1.invokeSuspend(ApiOperation.kt:22)
> at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:56)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:561)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:727)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:667)
> at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:655)

This is the code I am using

```
binding.payButton.setOnClickListener {

        val card = binding.cardInputWidget.paymentMethodCard
        val nameText = binding.nameInput.text.toString()

        binding.progressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        if (nameText.isEmpty()) {
            Utilities.alertBoxSingleBtn(this, "Please enter the card holder name")
            binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            return@setOnClickListener
        }

        val billingDetails = PaymentMethod.BillingDetails.Builder()
                .setName(nameText)
                .build()
        if (card != null) { // Create SetupIntent confirm parameters with the above
            binding.payButton.isEnabled = false
            val paymentMethodParams = PaymentMethodCreateParams.create(card, billingDetails)
            val confirmParams = ConfirmSetupIntentParams.create(paymentMethodParams, clientSecretKey!!)
            stripe.confirmSetupIntent(this, confirmParams)

        } else {
            Utilities.alertBoxSingleBtn(this, "Invalid card details")
            binding.payButton.isEnabled = true
            binding.progressBar.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
```

I experimented by using try-catch around all statements. But none of the statement is catching the exception. Please help with the issue

Comment: There are [some error-handling examples](https://www.javatips.net/api/stripe-android-master/stripe/src/test/java/com/stripe/android/net/StripeApiHandlerTest.java) that may provide a good starting point.